# call function in createReadStream nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to use async function in code below. but, got error method is not defined:

```
fs.createReadStream('temp/file.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', async function(data){
                name = data[1].name
                info = await this.method(name)
         }


async method(name){
        return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `this` is not referred to your global scope in that case.

Call your method without `this`, just `method()`